# AJAX Request code working in Eclipse but not browser

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, eclipse

I am writing a simple AJAX code as a way to learn the basics and introduce myself to the concepts. The following code grabs the contents of a textfile located on the server and passes to a variable, popping into an alert box.

My problem is that the code runs perfectly in the Eclipse IDE 'Open with Web Browser' but nowhere else.

```
var http = createRequestObject();
var responseContent;

function createRequestObject() {
   var objAjax;
   var browser = navigator.appName;
   if(browser == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"){
       objAjax = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }else{
       objAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   return objAjax;
 }

function getContent(name){
   http.open('get', name);
   http.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (http.readyState == 4) {
          responseContent = http.responseText;
       }
   };
   http.send(null);
 }   

 $(document).ready(function() {
   getContent('newcontent.txt');
   alert(responseContent);
 });
```

Does anyone know why this might be? Is there a problem with the code? If so, why would it work fine in eclipse but not elsewhere?

Thanks

Comment: Any special reason why you are mixing jQuery and manual XMLHttpRequest?  Possibly, you don't have jQuery on the server.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski There's not really any reason i'm using jQuery for the document ready beyond I know how to quickly write a document ready function. I'm linking to a google-hosted jQuery file. My alert box just keeps returning "undefined".

Comment: because the `responseContent` is populated asynchronously and therefore when it is alerted it is most likely not to have been populated just yet. You should do any operation regarding the value in or after the callback is executed. And I recommend using a streamlined XHR (such as jQuery's, which you're using anyway)

Comment: Can you link me to any information on callbacks? I'm not sure where the callback would be occurring in this code.

Comment: In your implementation, there is an event listener that is called when the ready state changes. In jQuery, there is a callback function that is being passed to the AJAX wrapper to be called upon success/failure. You can easily find it it the appropriate documentation. In your code, the listener is most likely called after the alert, so it alerts an undefined variable.

Comment: Ahh, I understand now. It's firing too quickly for the ajax request. Do you know where I can find any information on callbacks which don't involve jQuery?

Comment: **THAT AJAX CODE IS HORRIBLE**, find a better example. You should never sniff for IE like that, IE allows for the native object, your code ignores that. Why are you using jQuery for document ready, but not jQuery's Ajax methods?

Comment: @epascarello "I always tell people it is great to work with a tutorial to see how the XMLHttpRequest works. After you have learned how to do it naked, work with a library that fits your needs.

Eric Pascarello"

Comment: @four33 I think that the direct work with bare XHR demonstrates how problematic and inconsistent that implementation is (across browsers). The thing to understand is the order in which things happen (request preparation, sending and reacting to state changes). After you understand this, I won't blame you if you never want to use the bare bones again and use a carefully built library instead. That's what myself and many others did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing into a short answer:

The `XHR` is sent in the `getContent` function and a listener is attached.

Then, `getContent` returns and the execution alerts the undefined variable `responseContent`.

At some point the XHR is answered, the `readyState` changes to `4` and listener is called.

It is only then that the `responseContent` variable is assigned.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Can you recommend any resources for learning ajax code that isn't "**HORRIBLE**"? Can you recommend any good libraries?

Comment: Well, jQuery is pretty decent and I tend to use it often. The API reference is [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). I have also used `mootools`, `YUI`, `ExtJS` and others in the past. They all get the job done. `ExtJS` is intended for quite complex applications and is quite heavy, `YUI` has a more modular structure (as does jQuery). The advantage jQuery has is that it is extremely wide spread (so help is available if you ever get stuck) and very light and well documented. It is good for quickly prototyping your projects.